# Abnormal method overloading result in Java

Tags: java, overloading

Could you explain in a detailed manner why the expected result is not correct? As most of the readers expect that the output is `Byte Char Int Byte`, but of course it is not the correct answer.

```
public class Tester {
    
    public static String test(byte b) {
        return "Byte ";
    }
    
    public static String test(char c) {
        return "Char ";
    }
    
    public static String test(int i) {
        return "Int ";
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte b = 0;
        char c = 'A';
        System.out.print(test(true  ? b : c));
        System.out.print(test(false ? b : c));
        System.out.print(test(true  ? 0 : 'A'));
        System.out.print(test(false ? 'A' : (byte)0));
    }
}
```

The correct result is `Int Int Char Int`.

Answer (score 7):

This is because overload resolution depends on the compile-time type of the argument expressions, not the runtime type of the argument. See JLS [15.12.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2):

The argument expression `true ? b : c` has the type `int`, so the `Int` method is called. This is specified in the [JLS 15.25.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2), where it is said that if none of the special cases match (none of them do here), then the type of the conditional expression is the type after applying [numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6) to the second and third operands:

> An expression appears in a numeric choice context if the expression is one of the following:
>
> - The second or third operand of a numeric conditional expression
> - [...]
>
> Numeric promotion determines the promoted type of all the expressions in a numeric context. [...] The rules are as follows:
>
> [...] (none of these rules match in the case of a `short` and a `byte` expression)
>
> Otherwise, none of the expressions are of type double, float, or long. In this case, the kind of context determines how the promoted type is chosen.
>
> In a numeric choice context, the following rules apply:

> - [...] (none of these rules match in the case of a `short` and a `byte` expression)
> - Otherwise, the promoted type is `int`, and all the expressions that are not of type `int` undergo widening primitive conversion to `int`.

This is why `true ? b : c` is of type `int`. The same goes for `false ? b : c` and `false ? 'A' : (byte)0`. It doesn't matter what the condition is. The type of the expression is determined by the types of the second and third operands.

As for `test(true  ? 0 : 'A')`, this can be explained by a rule that I omitted above, just *before* the last "Otherwise..."

> - Otherwise, if any expression is of type `char`, and every other expression is either of type `char` or a constant expression of type `int` with a value that is representable in the type `char`, then the promoted type is `char`, and the `int` expressions undergo narrowing primitive conversion to `char`.

In this case, the expression "`0`" is a "a constant expression of type `int` with a value that is representable in the type `char`".

One way to think about the type of a conditional expression, is that it's the smallest type that the expressions of both of the branches can "fit". For a `byte b` and a `char c`, `int` is the smallest type that can fit both of them. For `0`, and `'A'`, `char` is enough to fit both, as it is known that `0` is in the range of `char`.

Answer (score 3):

The [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2) converts its expressions to a common type in order for a variable to store its result.

Imagine if you had an expression like this:

`char v = <myCondition> ? 'a' : 0L;`

The previous statement would make sense only if the condition was true, but what about if this was false and 0L was to be returned? `long` and `char` are not the same data type. So, the compiler needs to find a common type, without losing precision, in order to allow both expressions to be returned and assigned to a variable suitable for both of them. The resulting data type is picked up regardless the condition's outcome.

In this case, `long` cannot be cast to `int` and then `char` as it would lose precision whereas `char` could be cast to `int` and then promoted to `long`. This is why the previous statement can be correctly written like so:

`long v = <myCondition> ? 'a' : 0L;`

In your example, the first ternary operator has a `byte` and a `char`, a `byte` can be promoted to an `int` while a `char` can be cast to an `int`. The other way around, where a `char` would be cast to a `byte` is not possible as this would cause a precision loss (a `char` occupies two bytes). By applying the same logic of promotion, you can also explain the remaining cases. Except for the third one, where you should apply the resolving table from the previously provided link to the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For the type of a conditional expression in Java, always [consult the JLS charts (Section 15.25)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

> | 3rd → | byte | short | char | int |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | **2nd ↓** |  |  |  |  |
> | byte | byte | short | bnp(byte,char) | byte | bnp(byte,int) |
> | Byte | byte | short | bnp(Byte,char) | byte | bnp(Byte,int) |
> | short | short | short | bnp(short,char) | short | bnp(short,int) |
> | Short | short | short | bnp(Short,char) | short | bnp(Short,int) |
> | char | bnp(char,byte) | bnp(char,short) | char | char | bnp(char,int) |

where the notation "bnp(x, y)" means the type that is the result of [binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) of *x* and *y*, and the form "T | bnp(..)" means that if one operand is a constant expression of type `int` and may be representable in type T, then binary numeric promotion is used if the operand is not representable in type T.

For the first 2 calls, we have a `char` and a `byte`, so the result is "bnp(byte, char)", or the type `int`.

For the third call, we have a constant expression of type `int` and a `char`, and the value is representable as a `char` (it's `0`), so the result is the type `char`.

For the fourth call, we have a `byte` and a `char`, so we back to "bnp(byte,char)", which is the type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Table 15.25-A in the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) describes what type the result of a `?:` operator is, depending on the contributing types.

Your first example involves `byte` and `char`, so the result is a bnp ([binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)) of these, and for anything but `double`, `float`, or `long`, the resulting type is `int`.

Same thing for the others.